# What is the best way to handle a race condition?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using angular with NGRX/store and I am doing an api call through an action. Then I select the result of this API call in my store.
I am using a facade so I am storing my selector inside observable.
My code is:

```
this.facade.getDescription(); // API Call
this.productDescription$ = this.facade.productDescription$;
```

And then in my template file, I am subscribing to that observable using async pipe.

My object came back empty as the initialState was empty and I think that it was selecting the data faster than the response of the API call.

So to handle this I am adding a variable in my reducer called 'isLoading'.
And I am putting this in my template with `*ngIf="!isLoading"`

Is there another way like using concatMap or something to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the observable directly in the ngIf, something like.:

```
ngIf="!!(this.productDescription$ | async) as productDesc"
```

By the way, ou can then use productDesc in your template directly, no need to resubscribe to the observable.

Comment: This is what I did and it's not rendering of I am not adding isLoading. But I put my subscription in template only but later I will need to move it to Ts file as I 'eed to manipulate data